# Google plus login access token retriew

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, access-token

I need to get access token and send it to the server. With that access token server should get all user details, like name, profile picture and email.

I can get access token using **Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN** and **Scopes.PLUS_ME**, but with that access token server can't get user email.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;


    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;
            String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_ME;
            try {
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),
                        scope);
                appUser.setToken(token);
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                // Network or server error, try later
                Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // Recover (with e.getIntent())                
            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                // assuming you have already verified that 
                // Google Play services is installed.
                Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
            }

            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + appUser.getToken());
            // Get user's information
        }

    };


}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I want to use your code. Can you explain me what is appUser and setToken() here ?

Comment: It's POJO class and setter and getter. You can store result without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

I tested the other scopes and only that one appears to return the users email.  You can test the different scopes and what they return here: [People: get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get).

Note: I'm not an android programmer, you will probably have better luck finding out how to request that scope with android. I am looking, but haven't been able to find it.

Looks like the scope might just be email https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email

Comment: How my final scopes shoud look?  String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_ME + " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email ";

Comment: That is probably not going to work.  you need to find the correct Scope for use with android.  That's the actually scope used by the api.

Comment: see if there is one called Scopes.email or something like that

Comment: Yep it doesn't work, but Android doesn't have any email scope. http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes.html

Comment: Just email scope? Something like this? String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_ME + " email" ?

Comment: I'm sure it does have a scope just probably not as part of the play services.  I'm still looking.  I wonder why they make this so hard its easy with every other language.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address

Comment: I modified this code a little bit, but it works. You should edit answer with that code or link.

Comment: I think its a better idea that you edit my answer with the code you used to fix it.